# Why does adding a decimal point to an input clear the input?

Tags: javascript, html-input

I'm doing a small number keypad in Javascript, and I can't add a decimal point `.` to an `<input type="number">` by doing:

```js
document.getElementById('2').onclick = () => document.getElementById('input').value += '2';
document.getElementById('.').onclick = () => document.getElementById('input').value += '.';
```

```html
<input id="input" type="number" value="3"></input>
<div id="2">click to add 2</div>
<div id=".">click to add .</div>
```

> The specified value "3." cannot be parsed, or is out of range.

But on the other hand, we *can* manually enter the decimal point with the keyboard when the input has focus.

Full example:

```js
var target = document.querySelector('#input');
document.querySelectorAll('.calcbutton').forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", evt => { target.value += evt.target.innerHTML; }));
document.querySelector('.calcpoint').onclick = evt => { if (!target.value.includes('.')) target.value += '.'; };
```

```html
<input id="input" type="number"></input>
<div id="calc">
<table>
<tr><td class="calcbutton">7</td><td class="calcbutton">8</td><td class="calcbutton">9</td></tr>    
<tr><td class="calcbutton">4</td><td class="calcbutton">5</td><td class="calcbutton">6</td></tr>    
<tr><td class="calcbutton">1</td><td class="calcbutton">2</td><td class="calcbutton">3</td></tr>
<tr><td class="calcbutton">0</td><td class="calcpoint">.</td><td class="calcenter">ENTER</td></tr>    
</table>
</div>
```

Why does pressing `.` clear the input?

Comment: If you notice correctly, when you input the . manually then click a number, the decimal point gets removed. This shows that the value of the input never is 3. even if you type it yourself. It only shows and waits for the value to become numeric again before setting itself.

Comment: Also please do not have IDs not starting with a letter.

Answer (score 11):

If a value is set (per JS), it works like the following (copy from specification)

1. Let oldValue be the element's value.
2. Set the element's value to the new value.
3. Set the element's dirty value flag to true.
4. Invoke the value sanitization algorithm, if the element's type attribute's current state defines one.
5. If the element's value (after applying the value sanitization algorithm) is different from oldValue, and the element has a text entry cursor position, move the text entry cursor position to the end of the text control, unselecting any selected text and resetting the selection direction to "none".

That means it is immediately checked whether it fits the pattern of a number, whereas on a user input, it waits to a later point (basically to allow the ability to add decimal points)

See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#dom-input-value-value for more information.

Comment: Can we make it wait for sanitization? in JS like with keyboard input?

Comment: No, I don't think you can. I think you're pretty much bound to the specification. Depending in what situation you are in, there might be the option to use a hidden input. If you're using React or something like that, you might want to use a `text` type and run you're very own sanitization.
I didn't read it through but you might also want to look into https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#eventtarget-activation-behavior and https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-dispatch but that seems to me like a bit of over engineering

Answer (score 5):

I suppose it's because of the number type of the input field and its sanitation (by the interpreter, see [@Felix' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73606328/58186)).

If you want to keep using the number field, an idea to work around it may be to use a hidden text field to fill the number field (using `parseFloat`). Here's a snippet (text field not hidden for demo), using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) for the handling.

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.matches(`.calcbutton`)) {
    const value = evt.target.textContent;
    const inpNr = document.querySelector('#input');
    const inpTxt = document.querySelector('#inputTxt');
    const hasDot = /\./.test(inpTxt.value);
    // only one dot allowed
    inpTxt.value += hasDot && value === `.` ? `` : value;
    return inpNr.value = parseFloat(inpTxt.value);
  }
  
  // for demo: hide text or number field to see what it's like
  if (evt.target.matches(`[data-hidden]`)) {
    if (evt.target.dataset.hidden === `txt`) {
      document.querySelector('#input').closest(`div`).style.display = `none`;
      document.querySelector('#inputTxt').closest(`div`).style.display = ``;
      evt.target.dataset.hidden = `nr`;
      return evt.target.textContent = `Hide text field`;
    }
    
    document.querySelector('#input').closest(`div`).style.display = ``;
    document.querySelector('#inputTxt').closest(`div`).style.display = `none`;
    evt.target.dataset.hidden = `txt`;
    return evt.target.textContent = `Hide number field`;
  }
}
```

```css
.calcbutton {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div><input id="input" type="number" readonly> Number</div>
<div style="display:none"><input id="inputTxt" type="text" readonly> Text</div>
<div id="calc">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="calcbutton">7</td>
      <td class="calcbutton">8</td>
      <td class="calcbutton">9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="calcbutton">4</td>
      <td class="calcbutton">5</td>
      <td class="calcbutton">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="calcbutton">1</td>
      <td class="calcbutton">2</td>
      <td class="calcbutton">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="calcbutton">0</td>
      <td class="calcbutton">.</td>
      <td class="calcenter">ENTER</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<button data-hidden="txt">Hide number field</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! Which one would be hidden and which one would be visible on the real interface? If the visible one is `input`, then the user might be surprised that "." is not written and they might click multiple times and think it doesn't work. If the visible one is `inputTxt` then the user cannot enter number with keypresses on `inputTxt` anymore? How would you do in this situation?

Comment: That's entirely up to you ;) Showing the number field is the way a *physical calculator* works (well, at least mine ... it shows an entered dot only after entering a following number), keeping the text field may be more intuitive for the user.

Comment: I've added a button for you to try out hiding the one or the other.

Answer (score -2):

```js
document.getElementById('2').onclick = () => document.getElementById('input').value += '2';
document.getElementById('.').onclick = () => document.getElementById('input').value += '.';
```

```html
<input id="input" type="number" value="3"></input>
<div id="2">click to add 2</div>
<div id=".">click to add .</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).